# How do I append an object into existing object in a table (Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

Empolyee class...

```
class Empolyee
public name: string;
public id: string;
public dep: string;

constructor(name, id, dep) {
   this.name = name;
   this.id = id;
   this.dep = dep;
}
```

typescript

```
emp: Empolyee;
ngOnInit() {
     this.serviceA.getEmpolyee().subscribe( 
          { data => emp = data; });
}

addNew(newEmp) {
    this.emp = newEmp; //this does not work.... 
}
```

html

```
<table *ngFor="let person of emp">
    <tr>{{person.name}}</tr>
</table>
```

When I attempted this I got below error

```
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'Sam John'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed.
```

So how do I append an object to emp? or was there something I didn't get? my goal is to add the new empolyee to the front of the table and display it. Somehow I cannot understand why the error is being thrown.

Here is a sample response returned from calling `getEmpolyee()`
returns the following....

```
  getEmpolyee() {
        return this.httpclient.get<Empolyee>('/getEmployee').map( data => data);
   }
```

The data sent back from service is below

```
"empolyee":[
{"name":"Reed Thomas","id":"5729","dep":"Sale"},
{"name":"Green Steve","id":"3268","dep":"IT"}
]
```

Comment: what is newEmp ? is it not an array or any other iterable?

Comment: is not array. it is just object

Comment: may be this is what you want https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-fcxi7x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to change your variable in controller, from

```
emp: Empolyee;
```

to

```
emp: Array<Empolyee>;
```

Based on the JSON model that you presents, you may need to do the following in *ngOnInit*:

```
data => emp = data.empolyee;
```

And in *addNew* function, so, you will use the array **unshift** function:

```
this.emp.unshift(newEmp);
```

Link to additional full example:
[Employee Angular code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-wsyotw)

Comment: no this is not array. is an object. i have tried above before you post this and it does not work

Comment: well, so you are appending another property in the object?

Comment: perhaps. I am new to angular I am not sure how this would work. I know from subscribed service that data comes in can be json so it might be a list of json object and the type got converted when initialized.

Comment: Ok, just to clarify... Your goal is receive an list of Employees from service, and add more employees in it?

Comment: yes that's right. I wanted to add to it and if possible in front of the list.

Comment: Ok, then what you need is an array of Employee in your controller. I'll update the example to you understand...

Comment: If I changed it into array then now i got the following problem. Type 'Empolyee' is not assignable to type 'Empolyee[]'.   Property 'length' is missing in type 'Empolyee'. On line  { data => emp = data; });

Comment: @logger your service seems to be returning a single Employee object, according to what you commented to me, I believe he should return a list of Employees. You may need to adjust this

Comment: @logger I update the code again with a detail that occurred to me, maybe it helps

Comment: @logger check out in the answer the example I created based on your scenario, maybe it might help to clarify the way that you must do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
emp: Empolyee[];
ngOnInit() {
     this.serviceA.getEmpolyee().subscribe( 
           data => this.emp = data.employee );
}

addNew(newEmp) {
    this.emp.unshift(newEmp);
}
```

Comment: arun, empolyee is not an array. error TS2339: Property 'unshift' does not exist on type 'Empolyee'.

Comment: how can this be possible if it is not an array? `*ngFor="let person of emp"`

Comment: I dont know either. my original code would display the table correctly. i m pretty sure i declared emp as an object. because emp is type of Empolyee class

Comment: can you try my answer and reply here. I also changed the return object to : `data => this.emp = data.employee`

Comment: data.empolyee does not exist. it can only be data.name, data.id, and data.dep

Comment: as per the `json` response,` "empolyee":[
{"name":"Reed Thomas","id":"5729","dep":"Sale"},
.....
]`
this is an Employee array object under `empolyee`. H... confused

Comment: if you are getting error, try once with: ` data => this.emp = data`

Comment: then there is a red line under this.emp saying "Type 'Empolyee' is not assignable to type 'Empolyee[]'. Property 'length' is missing in type 'Empolyee'. "

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your service returns just a single `Empolyee` (isn't that misspelled btw?).

So try doing this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>{{emp.name}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

This is really basic Angular though, so you should probably take a tutorial/course somewhere (the [official tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial) is pretty solid).

Comment: if it is return a single Empolyee then how come i was able to view both object in the table?